# Why did Bard fake out Donnie Azzof with a handshake here?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolf-of-wall-street

On the golf course scene in *The Wolf of Wall Street* (2013), while the narration about how Brad helped Jordan
Belfort by holding stock under his name continues, Brad pretends to
offer Donnie Azzof a handshake but then withdraws his hand at the
last moment:

> Brad: Who are you supposed to be, huh? Jack Nickle-Jew?

It seems "Jack Nickle-Jew” is a play on words that combines the name of
the famous actor Jack Nicholson with the word “Jew".

Why did Bard fake out Donnie Azzof with a handshake here?

Comment: Because he's trying to look cool?

Comment: I don't have the scene in front of me right now, but FYI, the famous golfer being referenced is probably [Jack Nicklaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Nicklaus), not Jack Nicholson.